# How to generate war file for deploy in WebLogic

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, weblogic11g

I'm new in `weblogic` and i'm try to deploy war file in weblogic
i use `intellij-IDEA` for generate war file and every time i deploy war file in weblogic i get the same error

> Message icon - Error Unable to access the selected application.
>
> Message icon - Error Exception in App Merge flows' progression.
>
> Message icon - Error Exception in App Merge flows' progression.

Comment: Are you using Maven, Gradle, or some other build tool?

Comment: as i know i use the default intellij building tools which is maven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for helping me 
i figure it out.
my weblogic.xml file in not exactly what should it be
after i use netbeans and generate weblogic.xml file with it 
the problem got solved

thanks a lot for helping me

Answer (score 0):

```
you can add this code in your pom.xml

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.javacodegeeks.examples</groupId>

    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin-example</artifactId>

    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>Maven war ::  example</name>

    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <packaging>war</packaging>



    <properties>

        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    </properties>



    <build>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>

                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>

                <version>2.6</version>

            </plugin>

       </plugins>

    </build>

</project>
```